# GPUImage - Does filter chain order matter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I've set up a bunch of sliders to manipulate the values of various GPUIImageFilters targeted by a GPUIImagePicture. My current chain order looks like this:

```
self.gpuImagePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self.image];
[self.gpuImagePicture addTarget:self.toneCurveFilter];
[self.toneCurveFilter addTarget:self.exposureFilter];
[self.exposureFilter addTarget:self.constrastFilter];
[self.constrastFilter addTarget:self.saturationFilter];
[self.saturationFilter addTarget:self.highlightShadowFilter];
[self.highlightShadowFilter addTarget:self.whiteBalanceFilter];
[self.whiteBalanceFilter addTarget:self.gpuImageView];
[self.whiteBalanceFilter setInputRotation:[self gpuImageRotationModeForImage:self.image] atIndex:0];
[self.gpuImagePicture processImage];
```

When I remove the tone curve filter everything works smoothly. If I use the tone curve filter alone I have no issues either. When I use the above implementation  processing slows down tremendously.

Does the order of the filter-chaining matter when it comes to memory management and processing, or did adding the tone curve filter to the rest of the chain just push this setup over the edge?

**EDIT:**

I've realized it might be worth mentioning how the sliders change the filter values. If the exposure slider is moved, for example, it triggers this code:

```
[self.exposureFilter setExposure:sender.value];
[self.gpuImagePicture processImage];
```

Comment: Without profiling it is hard to say something. Have you tried to profile GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, filter order doesn't matter, but it usually does. Some color-adjustment operations work in such a way that they can be rearranged without changing the output, but most filter calculations will produce slightly to significantly different results if you rearrange them. Think about it like arithmetic where you change the order of operations or move some parentheses around.

Now, when it comes to performance or memory usage, order usually doesn't matter. Branching operations are the only case where this comes into play (having a filter that targets multiple outputs, that at some point are blended or combined into one output). You don't have that here, though.

You do have a number of steps in the above, and there is overhead in every filter you chain. However, I'm surprised you even see a difference in performance, because the bottleneck in the above should be the creation of the GPUImagePicture. Instantiating one of those is far slower than any filter you'd perform on it, due to the pass through Core Graphics needed to re-render and upload the picture as a texture.

If you are reusing your toneCurveFilter or others, make sure that they are fully disconnected from all their previous targets before using -addTarget: again. It's possible that you're switching out pictures while leaving all the filters connected to their previous targets, meaning that each new picture will keep adding targets. This will lead to tremendous slowdown.

I bet something like the above is what's slowing you down, but when in doubt fire up Time Profiler and / or the OpenGL profiler and see where you're really spending all your time.